# Why did not work jQuery button in this code

Tags: jquery

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nrr5.png

what is my mistake ? why this click function is did not work ? i made this function without each loop, then that function working properly, but why did not work this place ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> NG - REPEAT </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>VERSION</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>ACTION</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tr">

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:'data.json',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                        console.log(data);
                    $.each(data.product, function(name, value)
                    {
                        var result = '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+value.name+'</td> <td>'+value.version+'</td> <td>'+value.price+'</td><td><button id="btn">Load</button></td></tr>';
                        $(".tr").append(result);
                    });
                }
            });

            $("button").click(function(){
                alert("hi");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Well he is not looking on HOW to make an event, but WHY it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your event listener after your loop creating buttons, so do something like :

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:'data.json',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                        console.log(data);
                    $.each(data.product, function(name, value)
                    {
                        var result = '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+value.name+'</td> <td>'+value.version+'</td> <td>'+value.price+'</td><td><button id="btn">Load</button></td></tr>';
                        $(".tr").append(result);
                    });
                    $("button").click(function(){
                     alert("hi");
                    });
                }
            });


        });
```

Comment: dear sir, im beginner for jQuery, can you explain more with example please

Comment: Did it work ? Or not ?

Comment: wow sir, it's workin correctly, your exellent sir, im very happy sir, thansk a lot.................................................................................., thanks to stackoverflow also

Comment: Feel free to validate the answer if that's the case, your problem was that you were adding an event listener before creating the button, so not event where attached to your buttons.